# Upcast to a Generic Type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {
 /// stuff
}

class B : A {
 /// stuff
}

class C<T> : B {
  /// stuff
}
```

Then somewhere completely different I have the following three methods:

```
public void foo(A a) {
}

// overload 1
public void bar(B b) {
}

// overload 2
public void bar<T>(C<T> ct) {
}
```

Now, for whatever reason, I need to call the "right" bar from foo given the actual type of A. That is, if A is actually of type B, I need to call overload 1 and if A is actually of type C (whatever T may be), I need to call overload 2. And for completeness, if A is not either B or C, do nothing.

Right now, I am using the IsAssignableFrom method of the Type class to decide if the upconversion to B is possible:

```
public void foo(A a) {
   if (typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(a)) {
      bar((B)a);
   }
}
```

But this takes in the C variants as well. So the question is, how do I perform this upcast? Reflection? dynamics? We are using .NET 4, so anything that was introduced in C# 5, I cannot use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dynamic`. It will make method resolution happen at runtime instead of compile time, so you'll get the one that fits actual instance type best.

```
bar((dynamic)value);
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. The one gotcha is that you have to have a reference to the Microsoft.CSharp assembly as well.

Comment: Given the note that "if A is neither B or C, do nothing", this dynamic solution won't account for that, correct?

Comment: It doesn't but combined with the IsAssignableFrom that I already had, it works.

Answer (score 6):

> Then somewhere completely different I have the following three methods:

That illustrates the first potential solution to your problem. Don't do it "somewhere completely different". Make `bar` a virtual member of `A` and have `foo` invoke it.

A second potential solution is to use the Visitor Pattern.

```
interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(B b);
    void Visit<T>(C<T> c);
}
class A 
{
    public virtual void Accept(IVisitor v)
    { } // Do nothing
}
class B : A
{
    public override void Accept(IVisitor v)
    { v.Visit(this); }
}
class C<T> : B 
{
    public override void Accept(IVisitor v)
    { v.Visit<T>(this); }
}
class P
{
    class Visitor : IVisitor
    {
        public void Visit(B b) { bar(b); }
        public void Visit<T>(C<T> c) { bar<T>(c); }
    }
    public static bar(B b) { }
    public static bar<T>(C<T> c) { }
    public static void foo(A a)
    {
        a.Accept(new Visitor());
    }
}
```

But let's suppose that you cannot modify `A`, `B` or `C<T>`.

> Now, for whatever reason, I need to call the "right" bar from foo given the actual type of A. That is, if A is actually of type B, I need to call overload 1 and if A is actually of type C (whatever T may be), I need to call overload 2. And for completeness, if A is not either B or C, do nothing.

The first is easy:

```
public void foo(A a) 
{
    if (a is B) bar((B)a);
```

However, the generic subtype is difficult; there's no mechanism for `if (a is C<?>) bar((C<?>)a;` unfortunately.

That you're going to have to do with either reflection or `dynamic`. Note that if `dynamic` is unable to find a matching `bar` at runtime then it will throw, not do nothing.