# Generic Method gets parameter type from superclass

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, this

I have a problem with a typed method in C#.
I want to invoke a inherited method of an object.
This method invokes a static method with "this" as parameter.
The parameter of the static method is generic.
I now want the generic type of this parameter to be the type of the first object.
But the parameter has always the type of the abstract class.

Here is the example:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    bool update()
    {
        Connection.Update(this);
    }
}

class Entity : AbstractClass
{
}

class Connection
{
    public static void Update<T>(T obj)
    {
        someMethod<T>()
    }
}
```

If I try to do:

```
Entity foo = new Entity();
foo.update();
```

Connection.Update will look in the Debugger like this:

```
public static void Update<AbstractClass>(AbstractClass obj)
{
    someMethod<AbstractClass>()
}
```

But I want this:

```
public static void Update<Entity>(Entity obj)
{
    someMethod<Entity>()
}
```

Is there any possibility to something like

```
someMethod<typeof(obj)>()
```

or anything else to solve my problem?

Comment: Generic type parameters are resolved at compile-time. You cannot do that without reflection.

Comment: Consider using the visitor pattern.

Comment: You may have to use reflection... however, this will cause a performance hit.

Comment: Is it not possible to make `update()` generic?  `update<T>()`, then called: `foo.update<Entity>()`

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question, and the answer was to convert the variable to a dynamic (if you are using .NET 4): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294240/upcast-to-a-generic-type. Not sure if it will work in this situation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler tries to infer the type of T parameter, in the base class it does not have information to infer Entity type. So you should provide information of the child type while you want to call the Update function.@Alexandr answer is a good one just an improvement adding type constraint to T type parameter to restrict it be a child of  AbstractClass

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T>
where T: AbstractClass<T> //restrict T as a child of AbstractClass<T>
{
    bool update()
    {
        Connection.Update<T>(this as T);
    }
}

class Entity : AbstractClass<Entity>
{
}

class Connection
{
    public static void Update<T>(T obj)
    {
        someMethod<T>()
    }
}
```

Comment: `this as T` is not safe. `T` is a subtype of `AbstractClass<T>`, but `AbstractClass<T>` is not necessarily a subtype of `T`.

Comment: @newacct "but AbstractClass<T> is not necessarily a sub type of T"?? it is not supposed to be. 
but if you meant AbstractClass<T> is not super type of T for all the situations  . Because AbstractClass<T> is abstract so its instance can not exist then for sure this is a sub-type of AbstractClass<T>.

Comment: @Mojtaba_Sarooghi: You cast `this` to `T`. `this` is not necessarily an instance of `T`, and thus the cast may fail.

Comment: @newacct you are right maybe also should be a an exception to test the type of this

Comment: Also, the bound the code compiles with or without the bound `T: AbstractClass<T>`. The bound is not used in the code.

Comment: A workaround: `public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T : AbstractClass<T>` Then the subclass becomes `public class ImplementingClass: AbstractClass<ImplementingClass>`, and you can always treat the `ImplementingClass` as being of the `AbstractClass` type.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the base class as a generic one, here is the example:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<T>
{
    bool update()
    {
        Connection.Update<T>(this as T);
    }
}

class Entity : AbstractClass<Entity>
{
}

class Connection
{
    public static void Update<T>(T obj)
    {
        someMethod<T>()
    }
}
```

Comment: `this as T` is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick fix then cast `this` to `dynamic` which will delay the type evaluation to runtime. However, consider using the visitor pattern.

```
public bool update()
{
    Connection.Update((dynamic)this);
    return true;
}
```

Visitor pattern:

```
public interface IEntityVisitor
{
    void Visit(EntityBase entity);
    void Visit(Entity entity);
}

public interface IEntity
{
    void Accept(IEntityVisitor visitor);
}

public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    public virtual void Accept(IEntityVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Entity : EntityBase
{
    public override void Accept(IEntityVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var genericType = typeof(Connection<>);
var specificType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(Entity));
var conn = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType);
```

Comment: `Connection` not generic type

Comment: That's right. Connection should've be Connection<T> and Update<T>() changed to Update()

Answer (score 0):

Any thing like `someMethod<typeof(obj)>()` does not exist as it would break the type safety of C#, because the compiler cannot know the runtime type of a parameter. However, you can get the true type object by invoking `obj.GetType()`. You can use this type object to call methods dynamically using Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

One solution on this:

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    bool update<T>()
    {
        Connection.Update(T);
    }
}
```

then,

```
Entity foo = new Entity();
foo.update<Entity>();
```